# How to move rows in a table view when your data source is a Results object?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a table view that pulls its data from a Results object. However because you can't move items around in a Results object, I have to use a List object to move rows around in a table view.

But if you convert data from Results to a List object (to use the List object for the table view), the List object is no longer reactive. Meaning it just contains copies of the data in the Results object.

So my question is:
When your table view pulls its data from a Results object, how can you move rows around in a table view?

Comment: If you move the rows, the results will auto-update. So, just add an observer to the results to refresh the tableView and when Realm is updated, it all happens automatically. You can also perform manual delete, insert and modify as well within an observe closure. See [React To Changes](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/react-to-changes/#register-a-collection-change-listener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an index property to your models. Either that, or you need to define a new Realm class that has an index property and a reference to the objects you want to define. I would recommend the first because it is simpler. Here is one way to do this.

I would implement a protocol so you can apply the same logic to other models.

```
protocol IndexableObject: AnyObject {
    var index: Int { get set }
}
```

Now conform to the protocol.

```
class MovingObject: Object, IndexableObject {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var index: Int = 0
}
```

If you add an extension to Results it would be helpful. Basically what you want to do is extract the elements with indices in the range of [fromIndex, toIndex] and store them in an Array so you can update the indices once you preform your "move". The filter ensures that you only update the indices that are necessary rather than all of the elements in your Results set.

```
extension Results where Element: IndexableObject {

    func moveObject(from fromIndex: Int, to toIndex: Int) {

        let min = Swift.min(fromIndex, toIndex)
        let max = Swift.max(fromIndex, toIndex)

        let baseIndex = min

        var elementsInRange: [Element] = filter("index >= %@ AND index <= %@", min, max)
            .map { $0 }

        let source = elementsInRange.remove(at: fromIndex - baseIndex)
        elementsInRange.insert(source, at: toIndex - baseIndex)

        elementsInRange
            .enumerated()
            .forEach { (index, element) in
                element.index = index + baseIndex
            }
    }
}
```

Usage in your UIableViewController would like this.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    try! realm.write {
        objects.moveObject(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
}
```

Just make sure that you sort by the index and link your objects up to a UITableView in a notification block. You should find plenty of info in Realm's online documentation on how to accomplish this.

```
lazy var objects: Results<MovingObject> = {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return realm.objects(MovingObject.self)
        .sorted(by: \.index, ascending: true)
}()

func observeObjects() {
    notificationToken = objects.observe { [weak self] change in
        self?.processChange(change)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to sort your array.

```
var results = [Results]()
```

So after the `results` are inserted. Try to sort them like this.

```
var filteredResults: [Result] {
    results.sorted(by: { $0.id < $1.id })
}
```

This will sort them from smallest ID to largest ID.

My example result struct

```
struct Result {
    let id: Int
}
```

Then in your [DataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) use this array instead of the first one. It will show in the table view in the same order.

Comment: Careful with this. Running Swift functions on Objc Realm objects can uncouple the results from Realm so they won't be auto-updating. A better bet is to sort using the Realm `.sorted(byKeyPath: "name"` function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to define the `Results` struct like this.

```
struct Results {
    var items: [Int]

    mutating func move(from: Int, to: Int) {
        let temp = items[from]
        items[from] = items[to]
        items[to] = temp
    }
}
```

In UITableViewDelegate, everytime you moved item, this method will be called & you handle data changes in that

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
    results.move(from: sourceIndexPath.item, to: proposedDestinationIndexPath.item)
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath
}
```

Comment: This is not correct... well, it is correct but not for the question asked. The OP is using a Realm [Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Results.html) object, which is not directly modifiable, not a struct.